# Name binding like mechanism for jax rs client request filters

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have just came across filters and interceptors in Jax RS. I added `ClientRequestFilter` to my client app to add media type header to requests, but I would like to restrain it to specific endpoint apis, as client app interacts with a number of other services. For server side filters there is Name Binding that could achieve that in a transparent way, but it's marked here https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.0.Final/javadocs/index.html?javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html that this functionality is solely available for server side filters and interceptors. Is there an analogous mechanism for client side filters ?

Comment: How would you use it on the client side? What would you bind it to? Server side we have classes and methods we can bind to. What does the client have?

Comment: On my client app, I have services calling jax rs Client with (post get methods), I wanted that my filter be called only for requests coming from a specific service, just the same way we do with resources on server side. Right now, on filter side, I do an if check on urls to run the filter only for specific urls.